# Need a Control in MVC to hold multiple records

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing my first MVC intranet and I've just come across a bit of a problem.
I have a model for my create page

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using CTTModel;

namespace TestingTool.ViewModels
{
    public class TestCreationModel
    {
        public Test Tests { get; set; }
        public Risk Risks { get; set; }
        public ICollection<TestField> Fields { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I need to create a a test that has a risk and a collection of fields associated. It must be done in the same process.

So, what I need is some control where I can add multiple records.

So that went I press Create, it is sent back to the controller and then I can add each record to a ICollection of TestField.

The tests and risks part works fine, I'm struggling with the field thing.
Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Is it just plain old "static" (hard-coded) data or is it from a datasource of somekind? What's wrong with the constructor of the class?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the constructor, I just don't know what control to use.

Comment: What control? Is it how to do it in the UI or where do you get the "problem"?

Comment: By control, I mean something in the UI, like a html control, that can hold records, like a gridview or something like that. So that I can use those record and save them in the controler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found out what I wanted.

What I wanted was a Master-Detail CRUD operations.

I found a nice tutorial here, http://hasibulhaque.com/?p=200.

Now it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

http://stack247.wordpress.com/2011/03/20/get-forms-post-values-in-asp-net-mvc-with-formcollection/

If you want to be able to add new values, I would recommend you do that with JavaScript,
I would use the jQuery library to do it.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp
html5 will contain a datalist that will make it a lot easier, though.

You mentioned gridview to hold the data, if you check out the gridview it's just a html table that's being rendered by the server similar to this:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/javascript/creating-a-mvc-3-application-with-razor-and-unobtrusive-javascript

Friendly advice:
don't use Webforms controls with MVC!